# When can you see the effect of your update, insert and delete during a Stored Procedure call?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a "how does the SQL server work internally"-question.

If I create 4 Stored Procedures:

```
SP1 - FetchNamesFromSourceTable (takes 10 minutes to run)
SP2 - UpdateNamesWithAttendanceInfo (takes 5 minutes to run)
SP3 - AddAddressToNames (takes 8 minutes to run)

SP4 - RunUpdate which will run SP1, 2 and 3 in sequence.
```

Now if we assume that the SP fetches names from table OriginalNames into table NamesWithAttendanceAndAddresses (this is just an example) and we assume that the NamesWithAttendanceAndAddresses is empty the first time I run this.

Now, if I call SP4 and then select * from NamesWithAttendanceAndAddresses after 16 minutes, will I see the result of SP1 and SP2 or will I not be able to see any result at all in NamesWithAttendanceAndAddresses until SP4 has completely run it's course??

Comment: This is regarding MS SQL server, so this is Transact SQL.

Comment: This depends on may factors like locking,isolation levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on transaction isolation level. Also, it has nothing to do with the procedures themselves, but with transactions.

In default transaction isolation level (`READ COMMITTED` in SQL Server) and up, your SP4 will be able to see the changes made by SP1 only after the update transaction in SP1 commits. Whether the SP1 itself returned or not is irrelevant.

With `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level (not recommended) SP4 will be able to see the changed data as soon as the data pages are updated in memory.

Comment: How about outside SP4? If I check from inside SP4 I get that I can see the results of SP1, but if I start up SP4 and check from outside, will it still be the same? I assume, yes, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The point here is that it really doesn't matter is it SP4, SP123, or anything else. If the transaction that modified the data committed the changes, everybody else will see it; if it's not committed yet, only processes running under `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level will see the changed data. (But it's not transactionally consistent and also could be rolled back, so...)